# Passport.js BasicStratagy retuns unauthorized to logged in user in a Rest API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am working on a Rest API with Passport.js. after I log in and use a secured endpoint, I get "unauthorized" as a response. what is more confusing is that after I call the log in function, I get a valid user. here is Passport config:

```
passport.use(new BasicStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password'
},
    function(email, password, done) {
      console.log("Email: ", email)
      console.log("password: ", password)
      User.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err) }
        if (!user) { return done(null, false) }
        if (!bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) { return done(null, false) }
        return done(null, user);
      })
    }
  ))
```

I used the following middle ware code to secure it: `passport.authenticate('basic', {session: false})`

Comment: If you disable the session mechanism, then what do you expect to happen?